# 'Does not implement Interface Member' error

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to C# so I'm still getting used to it.

I've had this code going where I want to control a character with a virtual joystick. I was testing whether the joystick would be responsive or now, but every time I try to play the scene, I get 3 `CS0535` errors saying:

> 'VirtualJoystick' does not implement interface member UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.OnPointerUp(UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData)'
>
> 'VirtualJoystick' does not implement interface member UnityEngine.EventSystems.IDragHandler.OnDrag(UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData)'
>
> 'VirtualJoystick' does not implement interface member `UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.OnPointerDown(UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData)'

Here's the code. It's fairly short.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class VirtualJoystick : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{

private Image bgImg;
private Image joystickImg;
private Vector3 inputVector;

private void start()
{
bgImg = GetComponent<Image>();
joystickImg = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
}

public virtual void onDrag(PointerEventData ped)
{
Vector2 pos;
if(RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(bgImg.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
{
Debug.Log("Test"); 
}
}

public virtual void onPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
{
onDrag(ped);
}

public virtual void onPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
{

}

}
```

I hope you guys could help me through this.

EDIT:

I have corrected the syntax, which was cause of why the scene was not playing. But the Debug.Log on OnDrag  code is not working. I'm getting this NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error. Again, I'm just following what the video says, and his seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared the methods `virtual`, since the base class declares them `virtual` already, you have to declare them with `override`.

So:

```
public override void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped) { }
```

Also note that with C# your naming should match exact, so `OnPointerUp` instead of `onPointerUp`.

Comment: You could also add the new keyword in front of your method definition i think

Comment: **Never ever do that** @JordyvanEijk It will not get called when the method is called on the base class. `new` breaks inheritance.

Comment: I know that but that is also a possibility. depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Suggesting that if OP wants to override a method is a very bad idea.

Comment: Of course, error on the Syntax. Thanks for pointing that out. I got it to play the scene after fixing it, but there was this NullReferenceException error when I was testing it with the Log saying: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. What should be my next step here?

Answer (score 1):

Correct your spelling, i.e. `onPointerDown` -> `OnPointerDown`. C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

When your class inherit from interface(s), it should implement all methods and properties declared on such interface(s).

In your case you must declare in your class the methods mentioned in the compiling error messages, respecting their parameters type and returning values, *all case sensitive*.

Interfaces are meant to make sure all classes that inherit from them implement such methods and properties. Therefore you could access those members without more knowledge about the class itself.

Interfaces do not declare method/property modifiers (private, public, etc). You can specify them as you see fit.

Answer (score -2):

idraghandler,ipointeruphandler,ipointerdownhandler  implement in this order

Comment: The order of interface implementations does not matter.